# Fiware IoT Agent JSON connection to MongoDB with authentication

Tags: fiware

I'm trying to configure the Fiware IOT Agent Json connection to MongoDB with authentication, but I always get the Authentication Failed error.

I'm running the services via docker-compose, and in the Fiware IOT Agent JSON I have the environment variables IOTA_MONGO_USER and IOTA_MONGO_PASSWORD defined, which correspond to the mongodb username and password.

Here I put some parts of my docker-compose:

```
 iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json:latest
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent
    depends_on:
        - mongo-db
    networks:
        - fiware
    ports:
        - "4041:4041" 
        - "7896:7896"
    environment:
        - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db
        - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_DB_PORT}
        - IOTA_MONGO_USER=${MONGO_USER}
        - IOTA_MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PWD}
        - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentul
 mongo-db:
    image: mongo:${MONGO_DB_VERSION}
    hostname: mongo-db
    container_name: db-mongo
    expose:
        - "${MONGO_DB_PORT}"
    ports:
        - "${MONGO_DB_PORT}:${MONGO_DB_PORT}" # localhost:27017
    networks:
        - fiware
    volumes:
        -  ./volumes/mongo-db/db:/data/db
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_USER}
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PWD}
```

The error log is this:
(Note: the user and password in the fields below appears fine, I removed it from the post for security)

> subsrv=n/a | msg=Attempting to connect to MongoDB instance with url "mongodb://mongo-db:27017/iotagentul" and options {"auth":{"user":"","password":""}}. Attempt 1 | comp=IoTAgent
> (node:1) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:1) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Warning: no saslprep library specified. Passwords will not be sanitized

> time=2023-08-14T21:12:11.543Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=9ad5f04f-8b95-4292-837e-54c57de0461d | trans=9ad5f04f-8b95-4292-837e-54c57de0461d | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DbConn | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=MONGODB-001: Error trying to connect to MongoDB: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo-db:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.
> at Connection.messageHandler (/opt/iotagent-json/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:19)
> at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Connection.emit (node:domain:552:15)
> at processMessage (/opt/iotagent-json/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
> at Socket. (/opt/iotagent-json/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Socket.emit (node:domain:552:15)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
> at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
> at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
> ok: 0,
> code: 18,
> codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
> }]

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Related https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/issues/739

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by [this PR in IOTA Node Lib code](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/1511) and will be available soon in the next version.